# How can I access child component data from a parent in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to access data from a single-file component in Vue, but can't find any way of doing it. I have tried using `$emit`, but can't get thath to work either. The data string has to be blank as it gets modified by an input field.

I have seen others' solutions here on SO, but either the don't fit with my problem or I can't get them to work. I want to try to keep it as simple and understandable as possible.

Comment: Share some code please :)

Comment: As a general rule, you should not reach into other components for their data. Show what you tried with `$emit`.

Comment: This answer might help you :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877688/how-can-i-get-selected-value-on-the-dropdown-with-vue-js/48877939#48877939

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the special attribute [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref):

```
<child-comp ref="child"></child-comp>
```

In JS:

```
vm.$refs.child.YOUR_DATA
```

Hope this helps!